# How to matched confirm password in android studio kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm a beginner on android studio kotlin, and today I try to learn how to matched password and confirm password error listener. But the tutorial that I found on youtube is in java code.

> MainActivity

```
if (password.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
    password.error = "Please enter your password"
    password.requestFocus()
    return
    }
if (confirmPassword.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
    confirmPassword.error = "Please re-enter your password"
    confirmPassword.requestFocus()
    return
    }
```

Please help me on how to do it. Thank You

Here some pic to clarify my question
Form this [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYiqy.png) to this [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZBq1.png)

Comment: Please clarify your problem?

Comment: @momt99 I have add some picture to make my question more clearly

Answer (score 0):

if you have any button like submit button then do this

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener{

if (!password.text.toString().isEmpty() && !confirmPassword.text.toString().isEmpty()) {

if (password.text.toString() == confirmPassword.text.toString()) {

//This is how you can check your password with confirmed password
//you have to check this on button click otherwise it will give you an exception

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: use else for error message if (password.text.toString() == confirmPassword.text.toString()) {

//This is how you can check your password with confirmed password
//you have to check this on button click otherwise it will give you an exception

  }else{ // Error here }